# Setting up DRBD on rackspace servers

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, drbd

Is it possible to do? I have been trying for the last couple of days to no avail. Every place I look says that the two machines have to have a partition of the exact same size, and you cannot partition hard drives on rackspace (according to their tech support). If it is possible, what would be the best way to install/configure it. Again, I've googled this, and put many long hours into trying to get this to work, so any answers would be greatly appreciated.

The VM's I'm trying to get this working on are both running Ubuntu 10.04(Lucid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is possible, try this guide
http://rackerhacker.com/redundant-cloud-hosting-configuration-guide/setting-up-a-redundant-database-and-caching-layer/
and just change the fedora part with the common apt-get install (and ubuntu guides)